# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to use a button to go to an anchor.

My JS code is:

```
    function scrollToAnchor(aid){
        var aTag = $("a[name='"+ aid +"']");
        $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top},'slow');
    }

    $("#AsGuest").click(function() {
       scrollToAnchor('FName_Ship');
    });
```

HTML button I'm using as the click:

```
 <input type="Submit" id="AsGuest" class="btn btn-orange" value="CONTINUE AS A GUEST" style="margin-top:5px;"/>
```

Area I'm going to upon click:

```
 <input type="text" id="FName_Ship" name="FName_Ship" value="James" onchange="$.ajax( { type: 'GET', dataType: 'json', url: 'dmiajaxsecure.aspx?request=updatedata&amp;fieldname=shipfname&amp;fieldvalue=' + this.value + '&amp;extra=' + rnd() } );" class="valid">
```

Comment: The variable `aTag` is undefined, check the value of `aid` and make sure your jQuery selector is fetching the anchor tag you want it to as this is where the error lies

Comment: Doesn't look like an anchor, more like an input ?

Comment: What happens if you type `$("a[name='FName_Ship']").length` into the browser JavaScript console while on your page?

Comment: `aTag` is not `undefined`. The `jQuery` selector doesn't match a valid element.

Comment: `$("input[name='"+ aid +"']");`

Comment: @adeneo I didn't even spot that it was actually an input!

Comment: @MarkWalters well "aTag" cannot be `undefined` itself, because jQuery won't return `undefined`. What's likely is that it's an *empty* jQuery object, so the call to `.offset()` is returning `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy exactly. Sorry, read the error message wrong. Also, [checked jQuery source (line 9560)](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js): `if ( !doc ) {
  return;
 }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`jQuery.offset()`](https://api.jquery.com/offset/) returns `null` when you it is called on an empty jQuery object. Check `aTag.length` before attempting to call `.offset()` method, most likely the anchor does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `a` tag by `input`, as it is the element you actually target.

```
function scrollToAnchor(aid){
    var inputTag = $("input[name='"+ aid +"']");
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: inputTag.offset().top},'slow');
}

$("#AsGuest").click(function() {
   scrollToAnchor('FName_Ship');
});
```